# React Native expo-permission deprecated what to use now?

Tags: react-native, permissions, location, expo

I am using Permissions from the expo-permission Library to get the location coords of the user:

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

const granted = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
```

The above works but keeps giving the warning that expo-permissions is deprecated.

If I use:

```
import {Location, Permissions } from 'expo';
```

it says  Cannot read property 'askAsync' of undefined.

Does someone know what i should use? I use sdk42

Thx!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As this [blog](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-41-12cc5232f2ef) by [Brent Vatne](https://medium.com/@notbrent) says,

> expo-permissions has been deprecated in favor of `module-specific permissions methods` You should migrate from using
> `Permissions.askAsync` and `Permissions.getAsync` to the permissions
> methods exported by modules that require the permissions.
>
> For example: you should replace calls to
> `Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA)` with
> `Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()`
>
> There shouldn’t be two ways to do an identical thing in a single SDK,
> and so we picked our preferred approach and are consolidating around
> it.

So now, you will have to use `Permissions` from individual packages

**For Location,**

Firstly, install `expo-location`

```
expo install expo-location
```

Then you can use it like this

```js
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
if (status !== 'granted') {
  console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
  return;
}
```

Comment: And how can we add permissions that a package needs but doesn't provide any `RequestXPermissionAsync()` function ?
I'm trying to use [a wifi p2p lib](https://github.com/kirillzyusko/react-native-wifi-p2p#startdiscoveringpeers) and I need differents permissions such as `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`...

Comment: Adding these permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` would do the job according to the docs in the package you mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

If someone comes here and wants to get permissions for `ImagePicker`, then according to the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) you should do this:

```js
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";


  const getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      alert("...");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Now with expo, each libs have their own permissions requests methods.

Example with Location:

```
let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
```

[Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/)

Comment: thx it works i upvoted the other because is was explained more detailed but your answer is correct!

Answer (score 2):

works:
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

const resultPermision = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
const resultPermisionCamera = resultPermision.status;

```
    if (resultPermisionCamera === "denied") {
        toastRef.current.show("Gallery permissions are needed");
    } else {
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3]
        })
```

........

Now, expo-camera works great, but also I believe something is pending on the side of the app.json.

Do you still need to add these lines?:
"permissions": [
"CAMERA",
"WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
"CAMERA_ROLL"

question for everyone here :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";

this.state = {
  hasCameraPermission: null,
  type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
};
componentDidMount = async () => {
  const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
  this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === "granted" });
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).